# C# and emoji codification

Tags: c#, ios, sql-server

I would like to know if there is any way to translate the stored emoji that I have in a MS sql server database back to its original value.

Here the scenario:

the row in the database looks like:

```
Hello ðŸ˜„
```

where **ðŸ˜„** should be the normal *smile face*; now avoiding the face that is in a database is it possible to translate **ðŸ˜„** back in the emoji or even the *square* symbol, that when it is copied back in word with Segoe UI Symbol turns out at an emoji?

Comment: Silly questions but what version of SQL Server are you using? Are you using a `nvarchar` field? Sql Server 2012 supports multibyte utf-16 collations which you have to set up. If not, consider sending back bytes to your C# code and use UTF16 IO encoder to take the byte stream.

Comment: it is SQL server 2012 and the field is nvarchar(max), the text is saved by the iOS app.

Comment: try `select convert(varbinary(max),myfield) [myfield]` and then use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byte[])` I believe that should work.

Comment: @MichaelB, I tried what you told me but with no luck, i created and imported in sql server the assembly with the function that translate from byte[] to nvarchar. With no luck the text at the output is the same with the "strange" characters.

Comment: Actually it looks like it storing utf8 code points, with byte padding. instead of storing the utf16 codepoints. It storing the sequence as `0xF0007801DC021E20` which is too long for an emoji code point. It should be 4 bytes of data not 8. Translating this to varchar and then to binary we get the sequence 0xF09F9884, roll that in to the UTF8 encoder and you get a smiley back. You can see that here: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode that it stored the UTF-8 sequence but with padding.

Comment: @MichaelB what you explained did the trick, thank you a lot!!! Now I will try to insert a smiley from sql studio (eg: Hello *square char*) and translate it into "Hello ðŸ˜„".
Thank you very much again!

Comment: It still seems like an issue that your app is sending UTF8 and storing it as UTF16. You shouldn't be translating it like this, your app should send UTF16 to the server, and translate the utf16 back to the client. You shouldn't be storing utf8 with byte padding, that is a bad thing! Also a quick tip, if you want to see your `Hello ` as a smile face try the following `select N'' for xml path('')`, note the `N` before the string, if you don't put it there it will become two `??`. Which is awful, as at least sql server could be consistent and tell you that it was 4 bytes not two.